# for what value of $x$ this function is positive?

Tags: calculus, inequality

$$g(x) =\frac{(1+x)^p
}{(1+x^p)},\ \ \ \ x\ge1,\ \ \ \ 0\lt p\lt 1$$  is this function $g(x)$ increasing.

to calculate this I took the derivative of $g(x)$ and tried to find out for what $x$ this function is positive $$g'(x)=\frac{p(1+x)^{p-1}
(1-x^{p-1})}{(1+x^{p})^2}$$
for calculting the interval where this will be positive I considered only the numerator because the numerator is positive,

$$\ \ \ p(1+x)^{p-1}
(1-x^{p-1})\gt0$$

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to know when $g(x)$ is increasing, i.e., when the derivative is positive, right? And you mean "because the denominator is positive", right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out when the numerator is positive (as this will determine when $g'(x)$ is increasing), you have to find it's root(s):

$$p(1+x)^{p-1}(1-x^{p-1})=0 \implies x=1.$$

Now all we have to do is to check if the values for $x>1$ are positive or negative. Take for instance $x=2$:

$$g'(2)=p(1+2)^{p-1}(1-2^{p-1})=3^{p-1}p(1-2^{p-1}).$$

But since $p<1$, $(1-2^{p-1})>0$, so $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing for all $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

By assumption $p > 0$, $1+x>0$ and $p-1 < 0$, so $p(1+x)^{p-1} > 0$. This means we can divide the inequality
$$p(1+x)^{p-1}(1-x^{p-1}) > 0$$ by $p(1+x)^{p-1}$ and get the equivalent inequality
$$1 > x^{p-1}$$
after rearranging. Now multiply by $x^{1-p}$ and get
$$x^{1-p} > 1.$$ Since everything is positive this is equivalent (take $(1-p)$-th root) to $x > 1$. So the function is strictly increasing for $x>1$.

edit: typo in conclusion.

Comment: That cannot be true - have you tried plotting the function?

Comment: @Lovsovs: See edit.

Comment: That seems better! :)